# display block with event target id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm try to display an item inside a list that has a class which is exactly the same ID on the other list. This would be activated when I click on the other list then it will find a match class on the other list then display it.

Here is the code I'm using basically the first list is in `display:none;`
List 2 is my menu on which in the list 1 would you like to display.

The first list should only have one visible item at a time.

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wubbs1ov/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="gallery-container">
            <li class="1723"><p>
      123
      </p></li>
            <li class="1725"><p>
      456
      </p></li>
    </div>
<ul id="gallery-list">
    <li id="1723">
        <strong>qwertyuiop</strong>
    </li>
    <li id="1725">
        <strong>asdfghjkl</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT:

```
    $("#gallery-list li").click(function() {    
            alert(event.target.id);
        $("#gallery-container li .wc-gallery").css("display", "none");
    });

    window.onload = function () {
         $("#gallery-container li p").css("display", "none");
    }
```

CSS:

```
#gallery-container li p {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It's **bad bad** to use the same `id` in one `HTML` document. Never do this. Nobody likes that, `jQuery` doesn't like that. I don't like it.</strike> Try using a class or a `data` property.

But.. scratch that.. you are not really trying to do that. But still.. it's better to use a `data` property :)

Anyways, to accomplish this with a `data` property, you can do something like this:

*html*

```
<div id="gallery-container">
  <li data-id="1723">
    <p>
      123
    </p>
  </li>
  <li data-id="1725">
    <p>
      456
    </p>
  </li>
</div>
<ul id="gallery-list">
  <li data-id="1723">
    <strong>qwertyuiop</strong>
  </li>
  <li data-id="1725">
    <strong>asdfghjkl</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*js*

```
$("#gallery-list li").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $("#gallery-container").find('li').each(function() {
     $(this).find('p').toggle($(this).data('id') === id);
  });
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/70cmmcwt/1/)

Comment: I'm using class and ID not both ID. just same value.

Comment: @MichaelPon Yes, forgive my rage ;)

Comment: One thing is that the first list should only have 1 visible item at a time

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @PierreDuc!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#gallery-list li').click(function() {    
    var targeeet = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + targeeet).children().css('display', 'block');
});
```

Try this.

Comment: try it again mate. I forgot. I'm using jquery here. Haha. I always use nativeJS and I forgot to append dot(.)

https://jsfiddle.net/wubbs1ov/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the id of the list you clicked:

```
    $("#gallery-list li").on("click", function() {
            alert($(this).attr("id"))
        $("#gallery-container li .wc-gallery").css("display", "none");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is :

```
$('#gallery-list li').click(function() {
      var target = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#gallery-container li").hide();
      $("#gallery-container li."+target).css('display', 'block');
    });
```

Check the example below :

```js
$('#gallery-list li').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#gallery-container li").hide();
  $("#gallery-container li."+target).css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
#gallery-container li{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-container">
  <li class="1723">
    <p>
      123
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="1725">
    <p>
      456
    </p>
  </li>
</div>
<ul id="gallery-list">
  <li id="1723">
    <strong>qwertyuiop</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="1725">
    <strong>asdfghjkl</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do an accordion?

```
$("#gallery-container li").hide();

$("#gallery-list li").click(function() {    
    $("#gallery-container li").hide();
    $("#gallery-container li."+this.id).show();
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wubbs1ov/11/)